# filling key in a dynamically associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, key

I need to fill 2 arrays from one, filtering on white lists.
Here is the code:

```
foreach($ct_list as $key => $value ){
    if ( in_array($key, $ct_load) ){
        $ct_options[$key] = $value;

        if ( !is_null ($ct_visible) && in_array($key, $ct_visible) ){
            $ct_default[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Second array ($ct_default) is fine.
The problem is i was expecting first array ($ct_options) to be something like (with 'value3' filtered for not being in white list):

```
Array ( 
  [key1] => value1 
  [key2] => value2 
  [key4] => value4 )
```

but what i get is:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => value1 
  [1] => value2 
  [2] => value4 )
```

Could someone please tell me what am'i doing wrong?

Comment: can you share `$ct_list` array. ex: `print_r($ct_list);`

Comment: you mean `key3`, not `value3`, was not found in `$ct_load` which is, I presume, the white list? Seems like `$ct_list` is not associative array.

Comment: Here is result from print_r($ct_list):    `Array ( [houserules] => Aides de jeux [article] => Article [page] => Page de base )`

Comment: It is. this array associates the machine name of a content type to the "human readable" name of this same content type.

Comment: then `$ct_options` must be associative too. if it comes out from that loop like that, it looks like afterwards it was changed to `array_values($ct_options)` and you don't show this part of code.

Comment: can you share `$ct_load `array. ex: `print_r($ct_load);`

Comment: Got it!! I was using a sort($ct_options) right after the loop to sort datas before rendering it. Many thanks n-dru :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer was found, thanks to n-dru.

I was using right after the foreach loop a sort($ct_options) instead of a asort($ct_options).
The values in $ct_options array then lost all indexes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking to see if $key exists in $ct_load, `in_array($key, $ct_load)` and under the code you say you want value3 to be filtered.

```
<?php

$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => "value3", "key4" => "value4");
$array2 = array("value1", "value2", "value4");

foreach($array as $key => $value ){
    if ( in_array($value, $array2) ){
        $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
    [key4] => value4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem exists [array_uintersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php#refsect1-function.array-uintersect-examples) function.